# MYSQL: select multiple elements (AND) in joined table?

Tags: mysql

So I have this three tables:

- product (p)
- product_has_component (phc)
- product_component (pc)

Product have multiple components, at least one, and table phc store info how the joining should go. So, I can check which components given product has - that is easy.

But now I want to do opposite check: after selecting multiple components, I want to know every product, that posses all of them.

I made this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phc.product_id
           FROM product_has_component phc
           JOIN product_component pc 
             ON pc.id = phc.component_id 
            AND (pc.component_character = 'A' OR pc.component_character = 'y')
```

And it returns products id numbers, that have either 'A' OR 'y' component.

But how can I get those having 'A' AND 'y' components?

Obviously, replacing OR with AND will return nothing, so I guess this whole query's structure is just incorrect.

I also thought about doing something like select all with 'A', then select all with 'y' and then try to find common produts, but this seem to be very ineffective solution.

Comment: Lose the DISTINCT. Add `GROUP BY... HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ...) = 2;` Oh, and change the bracket bit to `IN()`

Comment: Awesome; didn't thought about using having, eh :( Work's perfect, many, many thanks!

Comment: Feel free to add an answer and then accept it.